# Ограничить процессу доступ к файловой системе с помощью средств WinAPI / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, файловая-система

Доброго времени суток!

Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли с помощью средств WinAPI или .NET (вряд ли) ограничить запущенному процессу доступ к файловой системе компьютера (вовсе запретить внесение изменений либо разрешить вносить изменения только в определенные директории)?

Если такая возможность есть, прошу подсказать, как ней воспользоваться. Буду благодарен.

P.S. Я знаю, что в Linux есть системный вызов `setrlimit`, аналога для Windows, увы, не нашёл...

Comment: Можно запустить процесс от имени пользователя с ограниченными правами.

Comment: Знаю, такой способ на данный момент реализован. Но хотелось бы сделать это программно и именно для указанного процесса / всех дочерних процессов.

Comment: Ну так это можно сделать и программно. Кроме того, вы можете явно создать ограниченный security token посредством [`CreateRestrictedToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446583(v=vs.85).aspx) по идее. Запустить процесс можно через [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) и передать туда токен.

Comment: @VladD: Благодарю вас! 2й вариант подошел. Отправьте его как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx). Она позволяет запустить процесс от имени другого пользователя, которому вы можете «выписать» ограниченные права.

Если вы хотите ещё больше ограничить права вашему процессу, вы можете создать новый access token при помощи [`CreateRestrictedToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446583(v=vs.85).aspx), в котором оставить только реально необходимые процессу права.

---

Судя по всему, вы можете использовать также встроенные в .NET средства, как в [этом примере](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx). Код для запуска процесса, судя по всему, нужно размещать внутри

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
{
    ...
}
```